# Minecraft Infinite City Street

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I am creating a city in Minecraft. I want to create an infinite street. How do I do this? I only want it infinite in one direction, so one end should have an end.

Comment: Do you know how to use the execute and clone command?

Comment: @Penguin Yes, I do.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @Penguin `/clone` with a repeater and Redstone block. I think I can do it that way, but I don't know where to put them. I've tried a few things.

Comment: @Penguin Or should I teleport a rabbit and make the rabbit clone it and then teleport itself, and keep repeating that?

Comment: I'm not gonna leave an actual answer because I don't know the dimensions or anything of the sort and this relies on that, so I recommend `/execute`ing off of the player and `/clone` something towards the direction you want them to go in. I would recommend building off of the player instead of having another entity as that might not work so well. Yu can definitely try it though

Comment: @Penguin I'm doing it in a flat world.

Answer (score -1):

Put in a repeat command block `/execute @e[type=armor_stand,name=street] ~ ~ ~ clone (here goes the sample road coordinates x2) ~ ~ ~`
And then a chain command `/execute @e[type=armor_stand,name=street] ~ ~ ~ tp @e[type=armor_stand,name=street]` (in here depends what axis you want for x put `~1 ~ ~`,for y `~ ~ ~ 1`)

I think that will work.

Comment: You tested this command, right?

Comment: Yep,;probably has some writing errors